# Android: Cannot get data from mysql for select statement through php

Tags: php, android, mysql

i have a problem on retrieving data from mysql.
There are two type of select statement in my program.

One is **"Select * From abcTable;"**
Another is **"Select * From abcTable WHERE attribute = 'abc';"**

The program works well for the first one, but have error on the second one.

Before calling the mysql, i ouput the query structure and it works in phpMyAdmin.
After go to the php script..the query echo out is totally different.
Here are the code

I construct the query in this format and pass to query_string

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM abcTable WHERE attribute = \'" + attributeVariable + \';"
```

call mysql function 
(The query_string has no problem here ie. **"Select * From abcTable WHERE attribute = 'abc';"**)

```
//Call PHP Server to execute query
public static String executeQuery(String query_string) {
    String result = "";

    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/getdata2.php");
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query_string", query_string));
        System.out.println("GO TO?????" + query_string);
        System.out.println("GO TO PARAM???" + params);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        //view_account.setText(httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString());
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

        BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        inputStream.close();
        result = builder.toString();
    } catch(Exception e) {
         Log.e("log_tag", e.toString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

the php script
(The $query becomes **"Select * From abcTable WHERE attribute = \'abc\';"**)

```
<?php
/* Change database details according to your database */
$dbConnection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'name', 'pw', 'dbname');
$query  = $_POST['query_string'];
$result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }
print(json_encode($output));

} else {
   print($query);
}
?>
```

And the error show

```
01-20 05:01:48.687: I/System.out(359): <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in <b>C:\AppServ\www\getdata2.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
```

Thank you very much for help!!!!

Comment: Your query has failed, which is why false has been returned. You can check `mysqli_error` to see why it failed.

Comment: same error as above
telling that this line have error 
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

Comment: This is returning `false`: `$result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query);` Its returning false because the query has failed. Passing `$result` to `mysqli_num_rows` is going to fail because you are not passing a mysql result set, but because you are passing a boolean false.

Comment: Yes..just like i thought before, the query string have problem..

Comment: is it because the string become Select * From abcTable WHERE attribute = \'abc\';???
I duuno why it adds \ before ' after i pass it form the android program to php script

Comment: If you're using php < 5.4, you might want to check whether `magic_quotes_gpc` was on, which it was by default. See more information here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php
I urge you to redesign your server interface, because passing SQL queries along is just a bad idea. It'll require you to keep your client and servers perfectly in sync and opens you up to attacks on your DB server.